# Difference in dates between two columns by group

Tags: r, dataframe, date

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
id strt_dt     end_dt
1  2013-05-07 2013-05-13
1  2013-05-14 2013-05-20
1  2013-05-21 2013-05-27
2  2013-05-14 2013-05-15
2  2013-05-16 2013-05-22
2  2013-05-23 2013-05-29
```

I want to compute the difference in days between the end date and and start date for each "ID":

```
id strt_dt     end_dt    diff
1  2013-05-07 2013-05-13 NA
1  2013-05-14 2013-05-20 1
1  2013-05-21 2013-05-27 1
2  2013-05-14 2013-05-15 NA
2  2013-05-16 2013-05-22 1
2  2013-05-29 2013-05-29 7
```

The goal is to take the difference between "strt_dt" and the previous row "end_dt" for each observation by "ID" except the first observation for each "ID".

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `lag` from the `dplyr` library and by applying `group_by` to make it for each **id**, as follows:

`mutate`: creates a new column

`difftime`: finds the difference between dates (based on the unit specified)

```
new_df <- df %>% 
          group_by(id) %>% 
          mutate(diff = difftime(strt_dt, lag(end_dt), units = "days"))
```

This should give you the following:

```
     id strt_dt    end_dt     diff   
1     1 2013-05-07 2013-05-13 NA days
2     1 2013-05-14 2013-05-20  1 days
3     1 2013-05-21 2013-05-27  1 days
4     2 2013-05-14 2013-05-15 NA days
5     2 2013-05-16 2013-05-22  1 days
6     2 2013-05-29 2013-05-29  7 days
```

If you want to get rid of the word `days`, you may convert the diff result into numeric, as follows:

```
new_df <- df %>% 
          group_by(id) %>% 
          mutate(diff = as.numeric(difftime(strt_dt, lag(end_dt), units = "days")))
```

Hope it helps.